# Django url template tag gives NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: django, django-urls, django-templates, django-1.5

I've tried everything and I've read every question/answer on the subject and nothing is working for me. I'm hoping someone could offer another possible solution.

I have a couple of apps. One of them is `ManagerApp` and one of them is `Accounts`.

In the `Accounts` app, there is view called `view_user`. It's described in the url file as

```
url(r'^user/view/(?P<username>.+)/$', views.view_user, name='view_user')
```

In the `base.html`, there is a header bar which has the users name. When he clicks his name, I want him to be taken to his personal profile page. So it reads as follows;

```
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'accounts.views.view_user' user.username %}">{{user.username}}</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
          {% endif %}
...
```

But when I try loading the page I get a

```
**NoReverseMatch at /ManagerApp/main/
Reverse for 'accounts.views.view_user' with arguments '(u'johnny',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.**
```

Why is this happening? I'm using quotes, the syntax is all right. The UrlConf is named properly, etc. I just can't see the problem and it's been an hour :-(

**Added**

This is the View definition:

```
def view_user(request, username):
    ''' Shows user data '''
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username = username) #check if user name exist    
    groups = Group.objects.filter(users = user)
    context = {'user': user, 'groupsOfUser': groups}
    return render(request, 'accounts/view_user.html', context)
```

Comment: why dont you use the value from url's param `name` instead? (ie. `{% url 'view_user' username=user.username %}`. Also your parameter is so called named parameter so you have to pass it even with its name (`username`)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko How would Django know where `'view_user'` is if I don't specify the app name? Remember, this view is in a different app.

Comment: Well... the only thing I can suggest now is to systematically test each part. Start off by removing all parameter requirements and just use `url(r'^user/view/$', views.view_user, name='view_user')`. Modify your view fucntion to remove the parameter as well: `def view_user(request):`. If it still doesn't work, you need to dig deeper to see why the URL wasn't loaded. If it works, then it's probably something with the regex. Personally, I always use numeric IDs in the URL and never username, since they can contain funny characters. Oh, and remove all view decorators too to isolate them as a cause

Comment: @user193130 ok thanks, I'll keep you posted...

Comment: ....AND THE PROBLEM WAS.... I didn't shut down and relaunch the server. When I did so, with the settings recommended here, it worked. Thanks for the advice everyone.

Comment: Lol it happens to me too. Especially since modifying the template files do NOT require a restart, but modifying the views / urls DO require a restart. Tricky!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a `username` keyword argument inside the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag:

```
{% url 'view_user' username=user.username %}
```

Also, as @yedpodtrzitko suggested, you can use a view name instead of the full path to it.

Do not forget to restart the server so the changes would take affect.

Comment: This is the reason why i dont like named arguments in URLs.

Comment: @Imray hm, ok, What is the error messsage now? (please include the full traceback) Thanks.

Comment: @Imray Try using `{% url 'view_user' username=user.username %}` as  yedpodtrzitko suggested. Looks like you supplied an invalid name: `accounts.views.view_user`

Comment: Even after @user193130 suggestion, still getting error: `Reverse for 'view_user' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'username': u'johnny'}' not found.`

Comment: @Imray is it saying in the error traceback about, what url it tried?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to open the main page which is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ManagerApp/main/`, but it extends `base.html` which is where this template is

Comment: @Imray ok, could you show your `view_user` view definition? Thanks.

Comment: @Imray Just wondering if the urlconf containing the `url(...)` is actually loaded... If you visit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/view/johnny/`, does it render the template you expected or a 404 error?

Comment: @Imray what if you replace `def view_user(request, username):` with `def view_user(request, username=None)`?

Comment: @user193130 If I remove the problematic line from `base.html` (which gives an error), yes it renders properly

Comment: @alecxe Yes it still renders properly

Comment: @alecxe See my comment under the question, and add to your answer. Then I will accept it. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1):

Which version of django are you using. If its old one means 1.3 then you might have to use the following line in the template file at the top

```
{% load url from future %}
```

If you are using django 1.5 then alecxe solution is perfect because other then that i don't see any thing wrong in the code/flow

Comment: I'm using 1.5 as tagged in the question

Comment: He's definitely using 1.5+ because django would've given a different error if he tried using quotes in `{% url '...' %}`...

Comment: @user193130 actually i faced a similar error when i was using older version of django. All was good except when i find out that you need to have use the tag that i mentioned above in the older versions. When i placed the tag things started working..:)